# Second tab redirect to login page when i am already logged in, In codeigniter Application

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function auth(){
    $nic    = $this->input->post('nic',TRUE);
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password',TRUE));
    $this->load->model('Login_model');
    $validate = $this->Login_model->validate($nic,$password);
    $this->load->helper("cookie");
    $autoLogin = $this->input->post("autologin",true);

    if($validate->num_rows() > 0){
        $data  = $validate->row_array();
        $nic = $data['user_nic']; 
        $name  = $data['user_name'];
        $email = $data['user_email'];
        $level = $data['user_level'];
        $sesdata = array(
            'nic' => $nic,
            'username'  => $name,
            'email'     => $email,
            'level'     => $level,
            'logged_in' => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($sesdata);

        if($level === '1'){
            redirect('Forget/dashboard');

        // access login for staff
        }elseif($level === '2'){
            redirect('welcome/officer_dashboard');

        // access login for author
        }elseif($level === '3'){
            redirect('User/User_Dashboard');
        }
    }else{
        echo $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Username or Password is Wrong');
        redirect('welcome');
    }
  }
}
```

This is my user auth function which redirects to ages upon user levels. I have many views as per the User levels.
But whenever I have loggedin, the second tab base url redirects to Login page again.
TIA

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5 for password hashing! [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even states: _"Warning - It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: Thank You.
but my problem is regarding the sessions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Welcome controller, Check the session data is_logged in, If data available act according to it

```
public function index()
{
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('nic');

        if (!empty($session_id))
    {
         $this->load->view('login');
    } 
    else
    {
            redirect('welcome/auth');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug the session data(using print statements) and make sure that you have added proper conditions in each page based on session data

Comment: How..? and what are the conditions  to be added in each page.? I am already redirecting pages as according to the login user levels..